# Akka Stream - Parallel Processing with Partition

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm looking for a way to implement/use Fan-out which takes 1 input, and broadcast to N outputs parallel, the difference is that i want to partition them.

**Example:** 1 input can emit to 4 different outputs, and other input can emit to 2 others outputs, depends on some function `f`

```
source ~> partitionWithBroadcast // Outputs to some subset of [0,3] outputs
partitionWithBroadcast(0) ~> ...
partitionWithBroadcast(1) ~> ...
partitionWithBroadcast(2) ~> ...
partitionWithBroadcast(3) ~> ...
```

I was searching in the Akka documentation but couldn't found any flow which can be suitable

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes to mind is a `FanOutShape` with filters attached to each output. **NOTE:** I am not using the standard [`Partition` operator](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Partition.html) because it emits to just 1 output. The question asks to emit to any of the connected outputs. E.g.:

```scala
def createPartial[E](partitioner: E => Set[Int]) = {
  GraphDSL.create[FanOutShape4[E,E,E,E,E]]() { implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val flow = builder.add(Flow.fromFunction((e: E) => (e, partitioner(e))))
    val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[(E, Set[Int])](4))

    val flow0 = builder.add(Flow[(E, Set[Int])].filter(_._2.contains(0)).map(_._1))
    val flow1 = builder.add(Flow[(E, Set[Int])].filter(_._2.contains(1)).map(_._1))
    val flow2 = builder.add(Flow[(E, Set[Int])].filter(_._2.contains(2)).map(_._1))
    val flow3 = builder.add(Flow[(E, Set[Int])].filter(_._2.contains(3)).map(_._1))

    flow.out ~> broadcast.in
    broadcast.out(0) ~> flow0.in
    broadcast.out(1) ~> flow1.in
    broadcast.out(2) ~> flow2.in
    broadcast.out(3) ~> flow3.in

    new FanOutShape4[E,E,E,E,E](flow.in, flow0.out, flow1.out, flow2.out, flow3.out)
  }
}
```

The `partitioner` is a function that maps an element from upstream to a tuple having that element and a set of integers that will activate the corresponding output. The graph calculates the desired partitions, then broadcasts the tuple. A flow attached to each of the outputs of the `Broadcast` selects elements that the partitioner assigned to that output.

Then use it e.g. as:

```scala
implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

def partitioner(s: String) = (0 to 3).filter(s(_) == '*').toSet

val src = Source(immutable.Seq("*__*", "**__", "__**", "_*__"))

val sink0 = Sink.seq[String]
val sink1 = Sink.seq[String]
val sink2 = Sink.seq[String]
val sink3 = Sink.seq[String]

def toFutureTuple[X](f0: Future[X], f1: Future[X], f2: Future[X], f3: Future[X]) = f0.zip(f1).zip(f2).map(t => (t._1._1,t._1._2,t._2)).zip(f3).map(t => (t._1._1,t._1._2,t._1._3,t._2))

val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(src, sink0, sink1, sink2, sink3)((_,f0,f1,f2,f3) => toFutureTuple(f0,f1,f2,f3)) { implicit builder =>
  (in, o0, o1, o2, o3) => {
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val part = builder.add(createPartial(partitioner))

    in ~> part.in
    part.out0 ~> o0
    part.out1 ~> o1
    part.out2 ~> o2
    part.out3 ~> o3

    ClosedShape
  }
})

val result = Await.result(g.run(), 10.seconds)
println("0: " + result._1.mkString(" "))
println("1: " + result._2.mkString(" "))
println("2: " + result._3.mkString(" "))
println("3: " + result._4.mkString(" "))

// Prints:
//
// 0: *__* **__
// 1: **__ _*__
// 2: __**
// 3: *__* __**
```

Answer (score 1):

First, implement your function to create the Partition:

```
  def partitionFunction4[A](func: A => Int)(implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed]) = {
    // partition with 4 output ports
    builder.add(Partition[A](4, inputElement => func(inputElement)))
  }
```

then, create another function to create a Sink with a **log** function that is going to be used to print in the console the element:

```
  def stream[A](log: A => Unit) = Flow.fromFunction[A, A](el => {
      log(el)
      el
    } ).to(Sink.ignore)
```

Connect all the elements in the **graph* function:

```
def graph[A](src: Source[A, NotUsed])
          (func4: A => Int, log: Int => A => Unit) = {

  RunnableGraph
    .fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val partition4 = partitionFunction4(func4)

      /** Four sinks **/
      val flowSet0 = (0 to 4).map(in => log(in))

      src ~> partition4.in

      partition4.out(0) ~> stream(flowSet0(0))
      partition4.out(1) ~> stream(flowSet0(1))
      partition4.out(2) ~> stream(flowSet0(2))
      partition4.out(3) ~> stream(flowSet0(3))

      ClosedShape
    })
    .run()
}
```

Create a Source that emits five Int elements. The function to create the partition is "**element % 4**". Depending on the result of this function the element will be redirected to the specific source:

```
val source1: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(0 to 4)

graph[Int](source1)(f1 => f1 % 4,
  in => {
    el =>
      println(s"Stream ${in} element ${el}")
  })
```

Obtaining as result:

```
Stream 0 element 0
Stream 1 element 1
Stream 2 element 2
Stream 3 element 3
Stream 0 element 4
```